# How to navigate back through Android preferences programmaticaly?

Tags: android, preferences

I have several preference screens. When user click on preference named `log-of` - I have to disable and hide some preference screens. Because of disabled preferences I need to go one `level up` in screen preferences hierarchy.

Looking for valuable suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decomposed preference hierarhy.
Now have 3 different xml layouts for each preference screen.
When user click 'logof' - I make change in app data and call finish activity. This returns me one level up :) This way causes more code, but logic is clear now.